# Get an escaped multi syntax sql update string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, enterprise-architect

I'm writing an add-in for Enterprise Architect, and I need to manipulate the internal scripts.
I would like to add my own function to an existing script.

The scripts are stored in the table **t_script** in the column **Script**.

Unfortunately the scripts are not exposed in the API so I'l have to work around that and use an update query on the database to update the script.

The problem is that scripts tend to use lots of characters that might pose a problem when using them in an sql update query, but I'm not very keen on writing my own escape function.

So what I tried was this

```
public void addCode(string functionCode)
{
    this._code += functionCode;
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("update t_script set script = @functionCode where ScriptID = " + this.scriptID );
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@functionCode",this._code);
    this.model.executeSQL(sqlCommand.CommandText);
}
```

I was hoping the sqlCommand.CommandText would give me the actual sql string that was going to be executed, but it doesn't. It is basically still the same string I created it with and it didn't replace "@functionCode".

An additional difficulty is that my SQL string needs to work on all DBMS types supported by EA

- SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008 and 2012
- MySQL
- Oracle 9i, 10g, 11g and 12c
- PostgreSQL
- MSDE
- Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere
- MS Access
- Progress OpenEdge
- Firebird

Does anyone have a better solution then writing my own escape function?

Comment: Expect the expected ;-) Of course you could ask the Sparxians to offer their internal procedure. Probably the same as asking the Pope to commit an error. So in the meantime do what you expected anyway: write your own stuff >:-(

Comment: I think the only really safe and sane way to do this would be using bind-Variables in the Select. You will need NO Escaping. - You just have to save the variables somewhere...

Comment: @Falco How do you mean? The problem is that I need an complete SQL String to pass to the Repository object. I don't have control over the actual execution of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I didn't really find some kind of existing functionality I had to resort to writing my own escape function.

This is what I came up with. It seems to work on MS-Access, FireBird, SLQ Server, MySQL and Oracle (I haven't tested the others)

```
/// <summary>
/// escapes a literal string so it can be inserted using sql
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sqlString">the string to be escaped</param>
/// <returns>the escaped string</returns>
public string escapeSQLString(string sqlString)
{
    string escapedString = sqlString;
    switch ( this.repositoryType) 
    {
        case RepositoryType.MYSQL:
        case RepositoryType.POSTGRES:
            // replace backslash "\" by double backslash "\\"
            escapedString = escapedString.Replace(@"\",@"\\");
        break;
    }
    // ALL DBMS types: replace the single qoutes "'" by double single quotes "''"
    escapedString = escapedString.Replace("'","''");
    return escapedString;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed the code after following the comments about the backslash escaping

Comment: Are you sure this works? Backslash is NOT an Escape Character in Oracle-Strings! If I want to insert Test'\ in Oracle, you replace it to INSERT 'Test''\\' and it will insert the Backslash twice!

Comment: @Falco No I'm not certain. I must admit that I haven't tested the backslash part on Oracle. Thanks for the hint. I'll test it and report back.

Comment: I think that the only correct way is to use the [Repository.RepositoryType()](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/automation_and_scripting/repository3.html) function to determine the SQL flavor and then use string concatenation operators and ascii to char functions to build the string literal. They will be different for each SQL engine used

Comment: @Falco I fixed the code example. As far as I could verify escaping the backslash was only needed in MySQL and Postgres

Comment: Good - this should work! Although you still probably will have problems, if the inserted Values are not only strings and numbers, but also Date-Values - I don't know if you insert Date/Time Values with these statements. I don't know how the standards for Date conversion are - in Oracle it is TO_DATE('...','...')

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should expect `SqlCommand` to resolve the parameters, that's done on the server.

As for the multi-DBMS problem, I'd have a look at something like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/). It's not something you can just bolt on at the last minute, but it does support most of the databases EA runs on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it, but right now it seems a bit like using a cannon trying to kill a mosquito.

Comment: Hmm. At least for MySQL you have to escape the SQL on the client side and move the result over to the server. AFAIK there is nothing like "here's the SQL with placeholders and here are the parameters". You use mysql_real_query and put the edited SQL in.